# Adding caption below Python Plotly Choropleth Map

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, choropleth

I want to add a caption below my plotly choropleth Map (using Python). I've looked into using annotations with graph_objs, but it only seems to work for locations within the map area. Is there a way to make the annotations show up below the choropleth map and/or is there an alternative way of doing this?

Right now I'm getting this but would like the caption to appear below the map area:
[image: current choropleth map]

I've tried inputting y values less than 0, but then the text annotations just don't show up at all.

Here's my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = df['CODE'],
    z = df['GDP (BILLIONS)'],
    text = df['COUNTRY'],
    colorscale = 'Blues',
    autocolorscale=False,
    reversescale=True,
    marker_line_color='darkgray',
    marker_line_width=0.5,
    colorbar_tickprefix = '$',
    colorbar_title = 'GDP<br>Billions US$',
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='2014 Global GDP',
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False,
        projection_type='equirectangular'
    ),
    annotations = [dict(
        x=0.5,
        y=0,    #Trying a negative number makes the caption disappear - I'd like the caption to be below the map
        xref='paper',
        yref='paper',
        text='Source: <a href="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2195.html">\
            CIA World Factbook</a>',
        showarrow = False
    )]
)

fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `y=-0.1` works fine on my end:

#### Plot 1

[image]

If that for some reason is not the case on your end (perhaps a version issue?), you should try to just leave it at `y=0` and rather make room below the figure utself by adjustin the margins of the plot like this:

```
fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=60, b=20),
    paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")
```

#### Plot 2:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_world_gdp_with_codes.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Choropleth(
    locations = df['CODE'],
    z = df['GDP (BILLIONS)'],
    text = df['COUNTRY'],
    colorscale = 'Blues',
    autocolorscale=False,
    reversescale=True,
    marker_line_color='darkgray',
    marker_line_width=0.5,
    colorbar_tickprefix = '$',
    colorbar_title = 'GDP<br>Billions US$',
))

fig.update_layout(
    title_text='2014 Global GDP',
    geo=dict(
        showframe=False,
        showcoastlines=False,
        projection_type='equirectangular'
    ),
    annotations = [dict(
        x=0.5,
        y=0,    #Trying a negative number makes the caption disappear - I'd like the caption to be below the map
        xref='paper',
        yref='paper',
        text='Source: <a href="https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2195.html">\
            CIA World Factbook</a>',
        showarrow = False
    )]
)

fig.update_layout(
    margin=dict(l=20, r=20, t=60, b=20),
    paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue")

fig.show()
```