# How to add custom data like "filename, email-id, created by" to plotly figure at the right end/top of the figure

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly-python, plotly-express

I am trying to add custom data like "filename, email-id, created by" to python plotly figure at the right top/bottom of figure. see attached image for reference. I gone through API documentation and googled it. But didn't find any useful information.  [image: Expected_final_image]

Expectation:
As per the attached image.

Comment: Actually, its task for me to explore and finish it. So, using examples of this link https://plotly.com/python/configuration-options/. On top of it, I have to add above details. I couldn't be able to find any parameters to add. so, i posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is annotate your figure. You should check out this [link](https://plotly.com/python/text-and-annotations/),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690131/how-to-put-annotations-outside-of-plotly-gantt-chart), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327378/adding-caption-below-python-plotly-choropleth-map), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637889/adding-annotations-to-a-bar-graph-in-plotly)!

One of the ways you can do this is through the fig.add_annotation() argument.

For instance, you can try to add the following code to add annotations to your figure and modify from there to see how it works.

```
fig.add_annotation(
   dict(
      font=dict(color='red',size=12),
      x=0.9,
      y=0.9,
      text="I want to add annotation",
      textangle=0,                               
      xanchor='right'))
```

You can make all kinds of customisations through the fig.add_annotation.